# How to find all products with some properties?

Tags: mysql

I'm listing product properties in a MySQL table where each row contains a product ID `prod` and a property ID `prop`. If a product has three properties, this results in three rows for that product. Example table:

```
prod | prop
-----+-----
1    | 1
2    | 1
2    | 2
2    | 3
3    | 2
3    | 4
```

How can I find which products have both properties #1 and #2 (product #2)?

The only way that I can think of is one select and inner join per property, but I think that would be very inefficient. It's a search function for a website and has to work for 10k lines in the table and 10 requested properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT prod
    FROM tbl
   WHERE prop IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY prod
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

And if there will be always 2 properties to find - then `INNER JOIN` would be a bit more efficient:

```
    SELECT t1.p
      FROM tbl t1
INNER JOIN tbl.t2 ON t2.prod = t1.prod
                 AND t2.prop = 2
     WHERE t1.prop = 1
```

The recommended index for this query to be efficient as much as possible is a compound one `(prop, prod)`

Comment: Is `(prop,prod)` the recommended index even if I use the grouping alternative?

Comment: @Andreas: nope, then only single-column `prod` should be used

Comment: For the first query, the index on `(prop,prod)` should be `UNIQUE` otherwise, somebody might insert the same (prod, prop) pair two times and ther results will be wrong.